# Subscription promotion before iOS 11.2

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit, in-app-subscription

**Background**

My app has a few subscription products, one of which offers a promotion e.g. 50% off for the first month.

**What I am trying to achieve**

When I query for the products via StoreKit, I'd like to know if one or more products have promotion enabled on a pre-11.2 iOS device.

**What I have tried**

When I query StoreKit for all products, StoreKit gives me an array of SKProducts.

If it's iOS 11.2+ device, the goal can be easily achieved by checking  SKProduct.SKProductDiscount, however, my app supports iOS9+ and pre 11.2 devices don't support SKProductDiscount(introductory pricing). Wondering if there is a way that I can achieve the same goal for users running on a **pre 11.2 iOS device**?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve; Either the user has an active subscription or they don't.  A non-nil `introductoryPrice` means that a free (or reduced) trial is available, but the user still needs to activate that trial through the IAP process.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've rephrased the question. introductoryPrice doesn't apply unless iOS11.2+ and my app supports iOS9+. I am basically asking if there is a introductoryPrice equivalent API for devices running an iOS lower than 11.2.

Comment: Prior to iOS 11.2 only free trials were available. These map to the "free trial" introductory price type in 11.2+. You know whether a given IAP has a free trial since you create it. You have to check the receipt to determine if the free trial has already been used, as you do with other types of introductory pricing.  If your IAPs have other types of introductory pricing then pre 11.2 users will simply pay full price from day 1

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11, appreciated it! Since introductory price is only available 11.2+, is receipt validation the only way to check if a product has a free trial for pre 11.2 users?

Comment: @Shawn do you know how can we get the free trial period for ios versions before 11.2. I've been having a similar issue. My UI shows how many days the trial is for. I'm getting this from SKProductDiscount object. How can I do the same(show trial period for different products dynamically) for versions iOS 11.2 earlier ?